# How to go easy on memory while iterating through a large CSV file in python?

Tags: python, csv

I currently have a csv-file with 200k rows, each row including 80 entries, separated by a comma. I try to open the csv-file with open() and append the data to a 2-D python list. When I try to iterate through that list and append the 80 entries to a single one, the computer freezes. Does my code produce some kind of memory issue? Should I work with my data in batches or is there a more efficient way to got through what I'm trying to do?

**In short:** Open csv, go through 200k entries and transform them from [1, 2, 3, 4, 5,..., 80], [1, ..., 80], .... 200k -> [12345...80]. [1...80], 200k

```
import csv


# create empty shells
raw_data = []
concatenate_data = []


def get_data():
    counter = 1

    # open the raw data file and put it into a list
    with open('raw_data_train.csv', 'r') as file:
        reader = csv.reader(file, dialect='excel')

        for row in reader:
            print('\rCurrent item: {0}'.format(counter), end='', flush=True)
            raw_data.append(row)
            counter += 1

    print('\nReading done')


def format_data():
    counter = 1
    temp = ''

    # concatenate the separated letters for each string in the csv file
    for batch in raw_data:
        for letters in batch:
            temp += letters
        concatenate_data.append(temp)
        print('\rCurrent item: {0}'.format(counter), end='', flush=True)
        counter += 1

    print('\nTransforming done')
    print(concatenate_data[0:10])
```

Comment: is it normal that `temp` is only initialized at start?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre What do you mean by normal? I just need this variable temporarily to hold the 80 single entries and transform them into a single one. That's why it is only included in the format data function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`format_data()` routine is bound to hog your CPU a lot:

- using `string` concatenation which is sub-optimal as opposed to other methods (`StringIO`, `str.join`)
- using the same `temp` variable in the whole routine
- appending `temp` in the loop (appending basically a bigger and bigger string).

I suppose you just want to do that: append all text as 1 string for each line, without spaces. Much faster done using `str.join` to avoid string concatenation:

```
for batch in raw_data:
    concatenate_data.append("".join(batch))
```

or even faster if you can get rid of the prints:

```
 concatenate_data = ["".join(batch) for batch in raw_data]
```

Comment: I figured out that much because it made no sense appending the same data over and over.

Comment: I'm so sorry, I completely forgot to set the temp variable back to an empty string. The goal is so append 80 single strings to one big and that for all 200k entries.

Comment: you mean that `concatenate_data` is a list of concatenated lines, or a huge string containing all the strings of the csv file, flat?

Comment: I mean a list of concatenated chars. So change [[a, b, c, d, ....], [a, b, c, d, ...], ....[]] to [abcd..., abdc..., abcd..., ...]

Comment: Thank you very much. Didn't know that .join is a lot faster that the usual concatenation. The prints are only there to debug :)